# Find $\tan x$ for $\tan(x+30°) + \tan(60°-x)$ = 2

Tags: trigonometry

What is the value of $\tan(x)$, admiting that

$\tan(x+30°) + \tan(60°-x) = 2$

I have no idea how to solve it

Solution : $2-\sqrt3$

Comment: are the angles in degrees?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes

Comment: Use the [angle sum formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities).

Comment: I used this formula, and i couldn't finish it: tan(a+b)
= (tan(a)+tan(b)/(1+tg(a)*tg(b))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative way to solve this problem is to set $y=x-15^\circ$. Consequently,
$$\tan(x+30^\circ) + \tan(-x+60^\circ) = \tan(y+45^\circ) + \tan(-y+45^\circ).$$
Using the formula
$$\tan(a+b)=\frac{\tan(a) +\tan(b)}{1-\tan(a)\tan(b)},$$
we get
$$\tan(y+45^\circ) + \tan(-y+45^\circ) = \frac{1+\tan(y)}{1-\tan(y)} + \frac{1-\tan(y)}{1+\tan(y)}=2.$$
By noting that $a+1/a=2 \implies a^2-2a+1=0 \implies (a-1)^2=0 \implies a=1$, we get
$$\frac{1+\tan(y)}{1-\tan(y)}=1 \implies 1+\tan(y) = 1-\tan(y) \implies \tan(y) = 0 \implies y =  180^\circ k,$$
where $k$ is an integer. Consequently, $x = 15^\circ + 180^\circ k$.

Lastly, using the half angle formula
$$\tan(a/2)=\frac{1-\cos(a)}{\sin(a)},$$
we get 
$$\tan(x) = \tan(15^\circ)=\frac{1-\cos(30^\circ)}{\sin(30^\circ)}=\frac{1-\sqrt{3}/2}{1/2}=\color{red}{2-\sqrt{3}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

use that $$\tan(x)+\tan(y)=\sec(x)\sec(y)\sin(x+y)$$
the numerator is given by $$\sin(x+30^{\circ}+60^{\circ}-x)=\sin(90^{\circ})=1$$
$$\cos(x+30^{\circ})=\cos(x)\cos(30^{\circ})-\sin(x)\sin(30^{\circ})=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}\cos(x)-\frac{1}{2}\sin(x)$$
$$\cos(60^{\circ}-x)=\cos(60^{\circ})\cos(x)+\sin(60^{\circ})\sin(x)=\frac{1}{2}\cos(x)+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}\sin(x)$$

Comment: What numerator?

Comment: $$\frac{\sin(x+y)}{\cos(x)\cos(y)}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\tan \alpha + \tan \beta ={\dfrac {\sin(\alpha + \beta )}{\cos \alpha \cos \beta }}$

$\tan(x+30°) + \tan(60°-x) = 2$

$\dfrac{\sin(90°)}{\cos(x+30°)\cos(60°-x)}=2$

Remember the formula

$2\cos \alpha \cos \beta =\cos(\alpha +\beta )+\cos(\alpha -\beta )$

and get

$\dfrac{2}{\cos 90°+\cos(2x-30°)}=2$

which translates in the much simpler

$\cos(2x-30°)=1$

$2x-30°=2k\,360°$

$x=15°+k\,180°$

hope this helps

Comment: It's easier to use the identity $$2\cos(x+30°)\cos(60°-x)=\cos(90°)+\cos(2x-30°).$$

Comment: @ProfessorVector Of course! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

We know that $\tan(90^\circ - \alpha) = \cot(\alpha)$. Therefore, $$\tan(60^\circ-x) = \tan(90^\circ - (x+30^\circ)) = \cot(x+30^\circ).$$
Now we can write the left hand side of the equation as follows:$$
\tan(x+30^\circ) + \tan(60^\circ-x) = \tan(x+30^\circ) + \cot(x+30^\circ)\\ = \tan(x+30^\circ) +\frac{1}{\tan(x+30^\circ)}.
$$

It is well-known that $a+\displaystyle\frac{1}{a}\ge 2$ only when $a>0$. The equality happens only when $a=1$. So your equation is simplified to$$
\tan(x+30^\circ) =1,
$$
which is easy to solve.

Comment: It's not the solution

Comment: Normally you solve an equation for $x$ and I think this solution is more compact and straightforward. $\tan(x+30^\circ) =1$ implies that $x+30^\circ = 45^\circ + 180^\circ\,k$ where k is an integer. So, $x= 15^\circ + 180^\circ\,k$. You can get different solutions by assigning different integer values to $k$. For example, when $k=0$ the answer is $x=15^\circ$. There are so many ways to find $\tan (x)$. For example, you can use $$ \tan(2x) = \frac{2\tan(x)}{1-\tan^2(x)}$$ to find $\tan(x)$ (simply put $x=15^\circ$ and use the fact that $\tan (30^\circ) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$).

Answer (score 0):

You have $$2 = \tan (x+ 30^\circ) + \tan(-x+60^\circ) = \frac{\sin 90^\circ}{\cos (x+30^\circ)\cos(-x+60^\circ)} = \frac{2}{\cos(90^\circ)+\cos(2x-30^\circ)}$$

So $$\cos(2x-30^\circ) + 1 = 1,$$

then $\cos (2x-30^\circ) = 0$, or $\cos 2x \cos 30^\circ + \sin 2x \sin 30^\circ = 0$, or $$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)+\sin x\cos x = 0$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(1-\tan^2x)+\tan x = 0$$

then $\tan x = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}}$ or $\tan x = \sqrt{3}$.

Comment: It's not the solution

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

As $30^\circ + x+60^\circ -x=90^\circ,$

$\tan(30^\circ+x)=\dfrac1{\tan(60^\circ-x)}=a$(say)

So, here  we have $$a+\dfrac1a=2$$